# Does `GitHub Pages` allow HTTP "Post" method?

Tags: php, html, git, http, post

I've programmed a little `php` Script, which just uploads a file from a user to the server.
I've tested in on my `XAMMP` Server locally, and everything worked fine.

But when i uploaded it to my `GitHub Pages` [Here](https://boahcss.github.io/), It got this error `405 NOT ALLOWED`
So i googled a lot and found out that i have to allow the HTTP `Post` Method.

**My Question is now:**
 How do i allow `POST` method on my github page?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's not PHP problem, but GitHub Pages webserver denying all HTTP POSTs. You should contact GitHub help, IMHO.

Comment: @LapshinDmitry Okay, i'll do. But isn't there any setting to allow that POST Method?

Comment: I actually think, since GitHub Pages is designed to serve static sites, it will not support POSTs at all, so your site is state-less, but it's only my thoughts on subject (that's why I am not answering, just commenting :) ). You can also edit question tags and title to get more answers from Github Pages users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GitHub pages can only serve static content, and there is no way to run PHP on GitHub pages or upload things. That's why GitHub doesn't allow POST requests.

If you need server side scripting (E.g. PHP), you'll need to use a web host which offers these things.

Comment: @balex, there's lots of (free) webhosts which _do_ offer PHP.

Comment: Yeah i know but i did so much SEO to my github page.. :(

Comment: A possibility might be to put _just_ the PHP code which requires PHP on another web host, and leave the rest on GitHub - or put in a redirect from GitHub to the new host. @balex

Comment: @balex the lesson is to always own your own domain, that way you are never stuck to one provider. True for email too.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub pages only support static websites/content, PHP doesn't work  on GitHub pages and GitHub doesn't allow POST requests.

try netlify, azure , or Heroku ect.