# Invalid Access Token Dropbox API Github pages

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, github-pages, dropbox-sdk-js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var filename = name;
//dataset is a valid JSON Object
var file = new File([JSON.stringify(dataset)], filename, { type: "text/json;charset=utf-8" });

xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'accessToken');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({
    path: '/Apps/BeachBlitz/' + file.name,
    mode: 'overwrite',
    autorename: false,
    mute: false
}));
xhr.send(file);
```

Is there any way for me to run the above code in Github pages?
Whenever I try, I get invalid access token error.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently github pages doesn't allow post requests according to [Github Pages allow HTTP Post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761926/github-pages-allow-http-post-method)

So the answer to my question would be no it's not possible unless you do this https://medium.com/pan-labs/dynamic-web-apps-on-github-pages-for-free-ffac2b776d45