# I can use data bases in pages uploaded git GitHub Pages?

Tags: html, database, github

I'm making a web page (a form) that needs a database to save the information that the users put; but I read in a post that all the pages uploaded w/ GitHub pages can't connect with those databases, is that true?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761926/does-github-pages-allow-http-post-method) answers your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does \`GitHub Pages\` allow HTTP "Post" method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761926/does-github-pages-allow-http-post-method)

Comment: GitHub pages only serve static content, but you can create a backend service somewhere else, and then make your form post to that backend service