# 405 on POST to /generate OpenAPI after deployment through Github Actions - NextJS

Tags: node.js, next.js, github-actions, openapi, http-status-code-405

I have a project on github that is playing with OpenAI API and creating some text and images from words.

Is is working locally, but when I published to Github Pages using the Github Actions - NextJS and try to hit the api /generate, the server returns a 405.

I have no idea why is not working, but locally is all fine and I can see the env has the correct openapi key secret. Any ideas ?

This is the page with the issue: https://rafaelaazevedo.github.io/rediskets/

and this is my project: https://github.com/rafaelaazevedo/rediskets

You can see it is working locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the reason why I am getting 405 is because Github Pages doesn't allow POST requests, just static content.

See more here: [Does `GitHub Pages` allow HTTP "Post" method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761926/does-github-pages-allow-http-post-method)

Will try to use netlify, heroku or https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/  Free tier to host the website and is without restrictions